# How to effectively deal with armed thugs as Catwoman?

Tags: batman-arkham-city

I've gotten to the late portions of the game, and I have trouble dealing with armed thugs as Catwoman. Okay, I can do ledge takedowns and corner takedowns and behind-the-back takedowns, but I can't get anywhere close to the speed in which I take them all downs as Batman - especially since I don't have access to the weapon disabler and the freeze gel.

Are there are tips to taking them down fast?

Comment: I haven't touched this since shortly after it came out, but I seem to recall Catwoman having a really quick disarm move of some sort...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In combat, you can disarm thugs with the Whip and knock them down using the Bolas. The caltrops can be used to knock down an entire group of thugs at once.

Out of combat, Catwoman simply does not have as many options as batman. Attacking several henchmen head-on carrying guns is asking for trouble. Use bolas from afar to knock them to the ground, throw caltrops along patrol routes, perform pounce attacks and use the bolas or the whip on nearby henchmen.

Comment: To wit, quick-whip-disarm is impossible on keyboard.

Answer (score 6):

I tend to spend the first couple of hits of any fight using the whip on armed guards (sounds kinky) to disarm them. Then some caltrops down around me to stop the others picking up dropped weapons.

Then while your in a flow, keep aiming towards anyone not trying to hit you, as they're likely running for a gun. Sounds counter-intuitive but keeping any of them from picking up a weapon is you main concern.

Comment: I do find this a bit easier as Catwoman, as she seems slightly quicker in combat that Batman.